# mono.android has conflicts with System.drawing of .net

Tags: mono, xamarin.android, pdfsharp

Recently I worked on creating PDF using PDFSharp on Mono. However, I found there is a conflict between System.Drawaing defined in Mono.Android and the "real" System.Drawing of .NET. Anyone has the same problem? What is the solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From various sources we can see that Xamarin.Android does not contain full `System.Drawing` namespace.

This is expected, as most of the namespace is built upon GDI+ (libgdiplus) which is not portable.

Thus, on Android you cannot use PDFSharp, and should switch to another solution, such as [XFINIUM.PDF](http://components.xamarin.com/view/xfinium.pdf). There are of course other vendors providing such libraries.